# How to access user profile in templates Django

Tags: django

How do you access user profile model in template. I have related_name set to "profile" on my profile model using a OneToOne field to User, but when I use {{user.profile.id}} it returns nothing.

Profile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name="profile", blank=True, null=True, )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,
                          primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

navbar

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  href="{% url 'dashboard' user.profile.id %}">Dashboard<span></a>
```

base.html

```
<body>
        {% include "navbar.html" %}
            {% if messages %}
            <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% block "content" %}      
        {% endblock "content" %}
        {% include "footer.html" %}
    </body>
```

signals

```
def CreateProfile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        user = instance
        profile = Profile.objects.create(
            user=user,
            username=user.username,
            email=user.email,
            name=user.first_name,
        )

        profile.save()

def updateUser(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    profile = instance
    user = profile.user
    if created == False:
        user.first_name = profile.name
        user.username = profile.username
        user.email = profile.email
        user.save()


def deleteUser(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = instance.user
        user.delete()
    except:
        pass


post_save.connect(CreateProfile, sender=User)
post_save.connect(updateUser, sender=Profile)
post_delete.connect(deleteUser, sender=Profile)
```

view

```
class UserDashboardView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = "users/dashboard/dashboard.html"
    context_object_name = 'profile'

    def get_object(self):
        return Profile.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get("id"))
```

Essentially what I am attempting to accomplish is to get the current user's profile.id in order to render the current logged in users dashboard. I have also attempted {{request.user.profile.id}} at no avail.

Comment: We will need "a bit" more information to have any chance to answer your question. I hope [this will help you update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ;-)

Comment: just updated. Hope it is a bit more clear now

Comment: We need more clarify as to how that navbar template is being rendered. What you have there works for me in my base.html, so not exactly sure what's going wrong based on your example.

Comment: I think I understand what you are looking for but I do not know here, and don't know how to test it. Si it's what I would have tried: `{{request.user__profile.id}}`. As a workaround, you can base your url pattern on `user.id` instead of `profile.id` or you could identify the profile in your view and get it in your template from the context (if you set a variable, like `current_user_profile`, you will be able to use it directly, with its attributes)

Comment: I just updated my question, I included my signals and base.html

Comment: That is also what I was thinking. Ill give it a try, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't actually save the newly minted profile in your CreateProfile function - so you never persist that profile to the database and it's lost when the function goes out of scope....

Also, why are you making separate copies for the email address and username in the profile when that information is already held by the user object? General good database design is to make sure you only hold information in one place only?

Finally, are you sure that you want the OneToOneField to be nullable? From the way the signals are setup it looks like you intend the Profile to be tightly coupled to the  User object - so it shouldn't be possible to divorce the Profile from their User by setting the user field to None.

Comment: So should I add profile.save() to my CreateProfile?

Comment: Yes ! That will make sure the Profile is persisted into the database.

Comment: Ill give it a try, Thanks again for the help.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I was able to use {{request.user.profile.id}}